# Is C++ Debugging in VS Code SERVER possible?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

ICT has implemented *VS Code Server* in our company (do not confuse with *VS Code*, which runs locally!). I would like to use it for C++ coding. We run the editor in web browser.

I was able to install C/C++ extension from Microsoft. Code highlighting and automatic code completion work as expected. I am able to compile `HelloWorld` code. However, I am struggling with debugging. I keep getting the following error message.

```
We can't launch a browser in debug mode from here. Open this workspace in VS Code
on your desktop to enable debugging.
```

The same issue was discussed [here](https://github.com/coder/code-server/discussions/5035) but without any obvious conclusion. Please note that *VS Code Server* does not seem to have `launch.json`.

I wonder, if C++ debugging is even possible in *VS Code Server*. If anyone knows for sure it is / is not possible, please let me know. If it is possible, I would appreciate a link with some instruction how to set it up...